# Convert date time to integer timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I convert this into timestamp

```
Datetime = 2014-07-14T09:34:47.000Z
```

Timestamp = ?

Comment: look for the javascript Date object, there's your answer.

Comment: `new Date(Datetime);`

Comment: That isn't even valid Javascript...

Answer (score 4):

```
var Datetime = "2014-07-14T09:34:47.000Z";
new Date(Datetime).getTime();
```

This will return the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getTimeStamp(dateStr) { //example: "2014-07-14T09:34:47"
  var s = new Date(dateStr); 
  return s.getFullYear()*10000000000 + (s.getMonth()+1)*100000000 + s.getDate()*1000000 + s.getHours()*10000 + s.getMinutes()*100 + s.getSeconds();
}
```

Note that you have to remove the milliseconds from your example.